# Parse a REST Response using Python

Tags: python, rest, api, parsing, python-requests

I am using python 'requests' to send a request to a server. The result is returned as a REST response. Now I need to get various fields or sections of the response object like ....
My requesting script is as:

```
import json
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.80.12:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.80.12:3128'
}
url = 'http://achecker.ca/checkacc.php'

payload = {'uri': 'https://www.google.com',
         'id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
         'output': 'rest',
         'guide': 'WCAG2-AA',
         'offset': '10'
         }

response = requests.get(url,params=payload,proxies=proxies)
print response.text
```

The part of result returned by the above script is as:

```html
<resultset>
<summary>
<status>FAIL</status>
<sessionID>8e03e40492a7f16a2b63c47b07588f81c746faca</sessionID>
<NumOfErrors>2</NumOfErrors>
<NumOfLikelyProblems>1</NumOfLikelyProblems>
<NumOfPotentialProblems>113</NumOfPotentialProblems>

<guidelines>
<guideline>WCAG 2.0 (Level AA)</guideline>

</guidelines>
</summary>
</resultset>
```

From the above result, I want to retrieve status, NumOfErrors, NumOfLikelyProblems, NumOfPotentialProblems. Beautifulsoup can be a solution, but i want to do it some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you are getting is in xml format. You need to convert the following xml string to a dictionary.
For the above task you can use xmltodict(https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict).
The process is as follows :-

```
import json
import xmltodict
response_text = response.text
response_dict = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(response_text)).
```

The Resulting dict for the above mentioned response will be as follows

```
{
  "resultset": {
    "summary": {
      "status": "FAIL",
      "sessionID": "8e03e40492a7f16a2b63c47b07588f81c746faca",
      "NumOfErrors": "2",
      "NumOfLikelyProblems": "1",
      "NumOfPotentialProblems": "113",
      "guidelines": {
        "guideline": "WCAG 2.0 (Level AA)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now it is just a dictionary and you can access the keys and their values.
I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Sir, I appreciate the timely response and this will definitely help me. But I am not able to retrieve the dictionary using:
    response_dict['summary']['NumOfErrors']

Comment: This is the error i get .. TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: To print the `NumOfError` use response_dict['resultset']['summary']['NumOfErrors']

Comment: response_dict['resultset']['summary']['NumOfErrors'] returns same error...

Comment: print response_dict['resultset']['summary']['NumOfErrors']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: I removed the Json stuff: response_dict = xmltodict.parse(response_text) and it worked for me... Thanks Sandeep Hukku